# How to define a geographic datum transformation using pyproj

Tags: python, transformation, pyproj

I originally wrote a script to project x, y coordinates. I shared this code with colleagues and we appear to be getting different results using the same script with the same files. We have different versions on python and pyproj installed on our machines. The issue occurs when projecting from NAD27 to WGS84. There are several datum calculations that can be used to do this.

How do I specify what datum transformation to use with pyproj so that I can state explicitly which one to use with pyproj?

```
import pyproj

inProj =  pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:26714')
intermProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:26914')
outProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:32614')
y1,x1 = [6023700, 344288]
y2,x2 = pyproj.transform(inProj, intermProj, x1,y1)

print y2, x2
```

I expect the x, y coordinates to be the same with different versions of python and pyproj but they are not.

Comment: Mind sharing the results and the versions of pyproj for each result?

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the `TransformerGroup` introduced in `pyproj 2.3.0`
https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/advanced_examples.html#transformation-group

Using it, you can select the specific transformation you are interested in from the available list:

```py
>>> from pyproj.transformer import TransformerGroup
>>> tg = TransformerGroup(26714, 32614)
>>> for trans in tg.transformers:
...     print(repr(trans))
... 
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (79) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: USA - CONUS including EEZ
- bounds: (-129.17, 23.81, -65.69, 49.38)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (4) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: USA - CONUS - onshore
- bounds: (-124.79, 24.41, -66.91, 49.38)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (3) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: Canada - NAD27
- bounds: (-141.01, 40.04, -47.74, 83.17)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (6) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: USA - CONUS west of Mississippi River - onshore
- bounds: (-124.79, 25.83, -89.64, 49.05)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (18) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: Mexico - onshore
- bounds: (-118.47, 14.51, -86.68, 32.72)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (13) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: Canada - NWT; Nunavut; Saskatchewan
- bounds: (-136.46, 49.0, -60.72, 83.17)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (11) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: Canada - Manitoba and Ontario
- bounds: (-102.0, 41.67, -74.35, 60.01)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (5) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: USA - CONUS east of Mississippi River - onshore
- bounds: (-97.22, 24.41, -66.91, 49.38)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (84) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: USA - GoM OCS
- bounds: (-97.22, 23.82, -81.17, 30.25)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (82) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: USA - GoM - west of 95°W
- bounds: (-97.22, 25.97, -95.0, 28.97)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + NAD27 to WGS 84 (83) + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: Mexico - offshore GoM - Tampico area
- bounds: (-98.1, 21.51, -96.89, 22.75)
<Concatenated Operation Transformer: pipeline>
Description: Inverse of UTM zone 14N + Ballpark geographic offset from NAD27 to WGS 84 + UTM zone 14N
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
```

You also want to check that you have all of the datum grids available for the best transformation (https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html#datum-grids).

Another piece that may assist you is specifying the `AreaOfInterest` also introduced in `pyproj 2.3.0` https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/v2.4.0rel/advanced_examples.html#area-of-interest